# reactor-netty TcpClient connection pool does not release connections

Tags: java, netty, reactor-netty

Using reactor-netty ConnectionProvider the connection is not released to the pool, so can not be reused, until disconnected

I found a workaround: disconnecting the connection after the response received, but it is terrible and can be appropriate only in my case when I connect to the neighbour server in the same network

```
clientsMap.computeIfAbsent("$host:$port") { hostPort ->
    TcpClient.create(
            ConnectionProvider.builder(hostPort)
                    .maxConnections(maxConnections)
                    .pendingAcquireTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(4))
                    .maxIdleTime(Duration.ofSeconds(10))
                    .build()
    )
            .host(host)
            .port(port)
            .observe { _, state -> println("state: $state") }
            //workaround as one packet is certainly less than 4096 bytes and the connection is stable enough
            .option(ChannelOption.RCVBUF_ALLOCATOR, FixedRecvByteBufAllocator(4096))
}.connect().flatMap { connection ->
    connection
            .outbound()
            .sendByteArray(Mono.just(send))
            .then()
            .thenMany(connection.inbound().receive().asByteArray())
            .takeUntil { it.size < 4096 }
            .map { it.toHexString() }
            .collect(Collectors.joining())
            .timeout(timeout)
            //the next line causes disconnecting after the response being read
            .doFinally { connection.channel().disconnect() }
}
```

when requesting data the output is

```
state: [connected]
state: [configured]
state: [disconnecting]
state: [connected]
state: [configured]
state: [disconnecting]
```

But this solution is much worse than returning connection to the pool and reusing it later

Expected to have a kind of `connectionProvider.release(connection)` method to forcibly return connection to the pool, and then I'd call it in doFinally, but there is nothing like that

if we comment the doFinally call, then `state: [disconnecting]` is not written and when more than maxConnections connections are acquired and not disconnected by the remote host yet, we catch

```
Pool#acquire(Duration) has been pending for more than the configured timeout of 4000ms
```

tested reactor-netty versions are 1.0.6 - 1.0.13

would appreciate solutions of returning connection to the pool and reusing it instead of disconnecting

Comment: did you find any solution for this?

Comment: @Jacob, no, I have implemented usual netty-client with own channel pool implementation, putting read messages into a hot-source flux